# Show jQuery 'waiting' gif when page is loading

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I have a moving gif of a loading bar. I had a look around to try to find a way of returning the current completion of a loaded page but it turned out to be overly complicated for my needs.

All I want to do now is display a gif whilst a page is loading, really its just so that the user does not think that the page isnt loading, not to serve any other purpose.

Is there a way to tell if the page is currently loaded or in the process of loading a new page so that I can display the gif at the relevant time?

At the moment, the gif is hidden when page is loaded and shown when a button is pressed. This works, but causes an issue when you go back in the browser to this page, where the gif remains showing.

If anyone knows of a good way of showing these loading symbols on a page, that would be great.

Comment: It seems to be linked to `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` not firing when you go 'back' to a page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the new page you can just show the loading gif normally and then use jQuery to hide it when the dom has loaded, this will not detect when images are still loading though.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

If you are using AJAX you could do something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(data) {
        $("#loading").show();
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        $("#loading").hide();
    }
});
```

EDIT: On the previous page to show the loading gif just do:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
  $("#loading").show();
  return true;
});
```

Comment: There are no doms loading. It is a completely new page. There are some server calculations going on in the background and when they are finished the it directs to the new page

Comment: If this is the case then you could display the page loading gif on the page that someone clicks a link to your new page.

Comment: I did something really simple in the end and just set it to always be invisible, then be visible when the ajax is requested :)

Answer (score 1):

### In JQuery the '.ready' event is triggered when the DOM is ready, while the '.load' event is triggered when all elements have been downloaded. You can use both of them to control the page status.

Ok, I read again the comments. So no DOM, there is a calling page waiting for the server to complete request and then to redirect.
So, from the calling page, why don't you execute an ajax request, so that you can control the gif displaying, the success result (fire redirect!) and the error result as well?

Comment: Ive tried: 

`jQuery('#wait').load(function(){
    jQuery('#wait').hide();
})`

But the problem still persists